# Laravel-mix installed but css and js files in the public folder has no content

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am trying to install the laravel-mix. I am having a hard time in installing laravel-mix. I already installed it but the files for css and js do not contain anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add Some Code to your app.scss and Compile again

Comment: @Ts8060 i'm not sure but based from an online training, by default after running "npm run dev", those files should contain something.. mine do not contain anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some sort of code in `app.scss` so that it compiles to `app.css`. After you write your stylesheets in `apps.scss`, run `npm run dev` to have it compile to `app.css`, and use `{{mix('dir/to/app.css'}}` in your `<script>` header.

Comment: shouldnt the laravel mix have a default content for the css and js files?